# changing point to colon for natbib

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I am using bibtex/natbib, with apalike style. Bibliographic items appears in the following way in my .pdf file:

Cox, D. (1972). Regression Models and Life-Tables. *Journal of the Royal Statistical Society.
Series B (Methodological)*, 34(2):187220.

I would like to know if I can change the point between "(1972)" and the title into a colon.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Answer (score 2):

This requires changing the `apalike` BibTeX style. Make a copy of `apalike.bst`, say `myapalike.bst`, and open the new file.
Locate the function `output.year.check`, I have it on line 116.
Change the function as follows:

```
FUNCTION {output.year.check}
{ year empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
    { write$
      " (" year * extra.label * "): " *  %% add colon and a space here
      %mid.sentence 'output.state :=     %% original apalike
      before.all 'output.state :=        %% change to that
    }
  if$
}
```

Save the file, ans use this style from here on.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\cite{StGu92}
\bibliographystyle{myapalike}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: sample output]